# Using EOT to echo multiple lines in a file

Tags: bash, files

I would like to write multiple lines to a file with the EOT, but the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
bench="X"
file_name="submit2.sh"
ids=(55)
for id in "${arrayName[@]}"; do
    cat <<'EOT' >> $bench/$file_name
    #!/bin/bash -l
    #PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
    echo $id
    EOT
done              # line 11
```

Gives this error

```
line 11: warning: here-document at line 6 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOT')
line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Note that you have various issues here: i) `ids=(55)` just sets the variable `$id` to the string `55`; ii) `for id in "${arrayName[@]}"; do` will fail since you don't define `arrayName` anywhere; iii) even if that did work, you would still always be writing to `X/submit2.sh`, since the values of `$bench` and `$file_name` never change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The end-delimiter of the here-document must be the first thing on the line:

```bash
for ...; do
    cat <<END_SUBMIT_SCRIPT
#!/bin/bash

... 
...

END_SUBMIT_SCRIPT
done
```

If you want to indent the lines in the script that creates the submission script, then use literal tabs at the start of the lines and do the redirection using `<<-DELIMITER`, e.g.

```bash
for ...; do
    cat <<-END_SCRIPT
        #!/bin/bash
        ...
        ...
        END_SCRIPT
done
```

The `-` in `<<-` will cause all initial tabs (not spaces) to be removed from each line of the here-document.  This also allows you to indent the end delimiter, as shown above.

Also note that if you want to expand a variable in the here-document, you should not quote the here-document delimiter.

Comment: You didn't specify the file name in the cat line.

Comment: @mahmood I did not, since I did not intend to rewrite your code but instead to show how to indent a here-document properly. To write the output of `cat` to a file, you still would do it as you do in your code, with `cat >>filename`.

Comment: Not a correction, just a comment about here document indenting:  I made the choice long ago to not indent here documents.  This usually means I put a one-line comment before the here document telling my co-workers that the next set of lines are intentionally not indented (so they don't try to "fix" the lines).  In some cases I move there here document to a separate shell function/subroutine so the lack of indentation doesn't ruin the readability of the code where it's used.